# Custom expanding function with raw=False

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': np.arange(1, 5),
    'b': np.arange(1, 5) * 2,
    'c': np.arange(1, 5) * 3
})

   a  b   c
0  1  2   3
1  2  4   6
2  3  6   9
3  4  8  12
```

I want to calculate the cumulative sum for each row across the columns:

```
def expanding_func(s):
    return s.sum()

df.expanding(1, axis=1).apply(expanding_func, raw=True)

# As expected:
     a     b     c
0  1.0   3.0   6.0
1  2.0   6.0  12.0
2  3.0   9.0  18.0
3  4.0  12.0  24.0
```

However, if I set `raw=False`, `expanding_func` no longer works:

```
df.expanding(1, axis=1).apply(expanding_func, raw=False)
ValueError: Length of passed values is 3, index implies 4
```

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Expanding.apply.html#pandas.core.window.Expanding.apply) says `expanding_func`

> Must produce a single value from an ndarray input if raw=True or a single value from a Series if raw=False.

And that is exactly what I was doing. Why did `expanding_func` fail when `raw=False`?

**Note**: this is only a contrived example. I want to know how to write a custom rolling function, not how to calculate the cumulative sum across columns.

Answer (score 3):

It seems this is a bug with pandas.

If you do:

```
df.iloc[:3].expanding(1, axis=1).apply(expanding_func, raw=False)
```

It actually works. It seems when passed as a series, pandas tries to check the number of returned columns with the number of rows of the dataframe for some reason. (it should compare the number of columns of the df)

A workaround is to transpose the df, apply your function and transpose back which seems to work. The bug only seems to affect when axis is set to 1.

```
df.T.expanding(1, axis=0).apply(expanding_func, raw=False).T
    a       b       c
0   1.0     3.0     6.0
1   2.0     6.0     12.0
2   3.0     9.0     18.0
3   4.0     12.0    24.0
```

Comment: Interesting. I will post this on the pandas Github page

Answer (score -1):

dont need to define raw False/True,Just do simple way:

```
df.expanding(0, axis=1).apply(expanding_func)
    a       b       c
0   1.0     3.0     6.0
1   2.0     6.0     12.0
2   3.0     9.0     18.0
3   4.0     12.0    24.0
```